# Decode javascript JSON.stringify to dict in Flask Python

Tags: python, flask

I converted an array `[5,10,1]` in javascript to store it in the cookies.

```
JSON.stringify(stored_list)
```

In my cookies stored as

```
[%225%22%2C%2210%22%2C%221%22]
```

How can I read this now in Flask Python as a dict for example? Because the following code does not work.

```
cookies = request.cookies.get('cart_ids')
print(json.loads(str(cookies)))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the JSON.stringify, it "urlencodes" the content. To decode this in python you can use `urllib`:

```py
import json
from urllib.parse import unquote

encoded_array = "[%225%22%2C%2210%22%2C%221%22]"
decoded_array = unquote(encoded_array)
assert decoded_array == '["5","10","1"]'

array = json.loads(decoded_array)
print(array)
# ['5', '10', '1']
# At this point it is a list of strings, that you can easily parse to integers using map(int, array).
```